# Sublime Text 3: Removing build systems

Tags: sublimetext3

This seems like such a simple task, but I've spent the last 40 minutes looking for an answer.

I'd like to delete a build system from Sublime Text 3. I've been searching for where ST3 stores their *.sublime-build. I can't find it via local search, documentation and other SO questions speak about ST2 (library/application support/sublime text...).

Could someone let me know how to remove build systems from ST3 on Mac Yosemite?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- OS X: **`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`**
- Windows: **`%APPDATA%/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`**
- Linux: **`~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/`**

You can edit it by additional plugin like **[PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)**

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences -> Browse Packages.Then click User and delete your build system.